# GROUP_CONCAT with null values Mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, group-by, group-concat

I am trying to make a query that groups all the terms associated with an ID, but it only shows me the ones that are related, how can I display the other ID's even though it is not related to any term in another table and concatenate null?.

My Mysql query is as follows:

```
SELECT
posts.ID,
posts.post_title AS product_title,
GROUP_CONCAT(terms.name)
FROM yxz_posts AS posts
, yxz_terms AS terms
, yxz_term_relationships AS term_relationships
, yxz_term_taxonomy AS term_taxonomy
WHERE (term_relationships.object_id = posts.ID) AND (term_taxonomy.term_id = terms.term_id) AND (term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id) AND (posts.post_type = 'product') AND (posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_tag')
GROUP BY posts.ID, posts.post_title
```

And the output shows only 29 results out of 140,000

The sample data is:

| ID | post_title |
| --- | --- |
| 82720 | METAL AXIAL |
| 87019 | TEST |
| 87020 | TEST 2 |
| 87021 | TEST 3 |

Expected output:

| ID | post_title | terms_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 82720 | METAL AXIAL | 11012-21010,22019-21020 |
| 87019 | TEST | 13201-25041 |
| 87020 | TEST 2 |  |
| 87021 | TEST 3 | 14567-20100,18760-22100 |

Thanks in advance.

Greetings from Chile

Comment: Start by rewriting comma joins as explicit joins, then add sample data and expected outcome as text

Comment: The output shows the values which are not present in shown source data ("13201-25041" and so on).

Comment: Exactly @Akina, but these data are an example representation, when executing the query, it only shows the data that is related, I want to see all the IDs of the products, regardless of whether they have a relationship with the other table or not. Could you help me please? Do you understand my question?

Comment: Personally I don't understand the question, It would help if you add representative sample date from all tables.

Answer (score 0):

@P.Salmon the new query is:

```
SELECT yxz_posts.ID, yxz_posts.post_title,
GROUP_CONCAT(yxz_terms.name) 
FROM yxz_term_taxonomy 
INNER JOIN yxz_terms ON yxz_term_taxonomy.term_id = yxz_terms.term_id INNER JOIN yxz_term_relationships ON yxz_term_taxonomy.term_id = yxz_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
INNER JOIN yxz_posts ON yxz_term_relationships.object_id = yxz_posts.ID WHERE (yxz_term_taxonomy.taxonomy like 'product_tag') 
GROUP BY yxz_posts.ID, yxz_posts.post_title
```